# FlexSlider navigation

Tags: navigation, flexslider

I use [FlexSlider](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/) for one very popular site and I have some sliders in it.

So how can I make every single slider to be with a different buttons - back and next.

Now every slider gets class - flex-direction-nav and all of them have similar buttons.

My question is how to put different class to each other, because I want to use different images (sizes and colors) for the buttons.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could wrap your different sliders with different container DIV's or give them both different classes?
Say I have 2 flexsliders, named flexSlider1 and flexSlider2

```
<div class="flexslider flexSlider1">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="flexslider flexSlider2">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And now access your different buttons in CSS like

```
.flexSlider1 .flex-next {
     background: ...
}
```